# How can I shorten the path of a DOS prompt?

Tags: cmd, prompt

My path on my DOS prompt is ridiculously long. How can I shorten this?

```
C:\RUBY\Ruby_Practice\prep-work-master\coding-test-2\practice-problems\spec>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right-click on My Computer|Properties. Then from the Advanced Tab, click Environment Variables, then add a new User Variable called PROMPT and set it to `$p$_$+$g`.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx

Answer (score 86):

To remove the path from the prompt use 'prompt $g' which will just show the chevron.  You can then use the 'cd' command anytime to see the directory you are in.  E.g.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>prompt $g
>
>cd
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

>
```

Comment: This may be a better answer, but I am glad they are both here.

Comment: Simple answer and sufficient, usually the best.

Comment: Use 'prompt' without any arguments to bring back the full path. Here is a full list of arguments: http://www.windowscommandline.com/prompt/

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the @Daniel's answer, if you want to go back to the normal state,
You can type `prompt` (without any arguments) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It's not related to the question exactly, but i find it more useful to this scenario. 
When we use this `prompt $G`, this changes the command prompt path to `>`. Even when you navigate to the sub folders, the prompt will still remain as `>` which is not much useful.

Rather than doing this, we can map the most used path to a virtual drive.
like `C:\Users\ram\Desktop\temp` to a virtual drive `X:`. By this way, you need not to see the unneeded path, as well as you can see the sub folder navigations like `X:\subfolder>`.

This is more useful to map your project to a virtual drive and do all the operations.

**To Map a path to a virtual Drive**

1) type `subst [Drive:] [path]`
Example: `cmd>subst X: C:\Users\ram\Desktop\temp`

2) Then go to the drive by typing `X:` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To back to the earlier mode, you can just type the corresponding drive letter. In this case `C:` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Nice! Thank you! You just upped my productivity!

Comment: Running the `subst X: C:\path` command (and accessing it with `X:`) will create a duplicate icon of the drive if you look at your mounted drives. To remove the duplicate you can use `subst X: /D`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a .bat file that displays the prompt with the final folder name in the current dir path.

```
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*
echo %CurrDirName%
prompt %CurrDirName% $G
```

Lines 1 and 2 come from [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/160712/236556) to SuperUser: "How can I find the short path of a Windows directory/file?"