# Shortening windows command prompt path while using virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, cmd, virtualenv

I am using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) within [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) to develop my `python` project in Windows.

The path to my project is very long, so I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391932/how-can-i-shorten-the-path-of-a-dos-prompt) to shorten the path. However, when I deactivate the prompt, the prepending "(env)" on the path is gone:

[image: command prompt image]

Is my virtualenv still active?

Similiar SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735128/customize-virtualenv-path-prompt-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406926/how-do-i-change-the-default-virtualenv-prompt) don't answer my specific question. No explanation for this situation found on [prompt](http://www.windowscommandline.com/prompt/) and [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) sites.

Comment: `promt $Cenv$F$G`? (Note: `prompt` without parameters restores the default promt). For the "virtalenv" promt: `prompt $Cenv$F$P$G`

Comment: @Stephan it worked! Thanks.

Comment: However, its not listed here: http://www.windowscommandline.com/prompt. Where did you get this command? Could you kindly provide the link?

Comment: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt) is a good source of help for `cmd` commands. This is the page for [prompt](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html).

Comment: @Stephan thanks again